# if several slices contain the same code, literally identical, but are intended for different components. Is it worth merging it all into one slice?

Tags: reactjs, redux

**If yes, how can I observe on multiple action Creators at the same time, the code is below**

```
extraReducers(builder) {
    builder
        .addCase(loadPlanet.fulfilled || loadSpecie.fulfilled || loadCharacter.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
            state.entity = action.payload
            state.status = 'idle'
        })
        .addCase(loadPlanet.pending || loadSpecie.pending || loadCharacter.pending, (state, action) => {
            state.status = 'pending'
        })
        .addCase(loadPlanet.rejected || loadSpecie.rejected || loadCharacter.rejected, (state, action) => {
            state.status = 'failed'
            state.error = action.payload
        })
}
```

This -> loadPlanet.fulfilled || loadSpecie.fulfilled || loadCharacter.fulfilled does not work, it also doesn't look like a normal thing.

So I can't understand to leave the same code in different slices or is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, a reducer should be about a certain type of data or about a feature, not about a certain component. Redux is the data layer of your application, it should not 1:1 replicate your component structure.

In this specific case I would recommend that you look into `createApi` of Redux Toolkit's "RTK Query" though - you really should not write this kind of data fetching logic by hand at all. Redux Toolkit can autogenerate that for you.

See the [RTK Query introduction page](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/overview) and the [Redux Toolkit tutorial on RTK Query](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-7-rtk-query-basics)